# Error "End tag div seen, but there were open elements"

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I was running the W3C validator on the internal pages on [my site](http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/07/04/furto-al-battente-cinque-arresti/) and I received this error:

> Error Line 332, Column 6: End tag `div` seen, but there were open elements.
>   `</div><!-- #content -->`

I have tried to search for `div` or similar that remained open but I can't find any of them.

EDIT: I add the code of the page

```
<div class="top1"></div>

<div id="headerwrapper">
    <header id="masthead">
        <div class="site-header logo-wrapper">
            <div class="logo-holder logo">
                <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it">
                    <img alt="" src="http://95.110.225.62/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pplogo.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="social-wrapper">
                <nav id="main-menu-wrapper">
                    <h6 class="clipmask">Menu Principale</h6>

                    <div id="main-menu">
                        <nav id="mobile-menu">
                            <h6 class="clipmask">Menu mobile</h6>
                        </nav>

                        <div class="ddsmoothmenu" id="menu-22">
                            <ul class="menu" id="menu-main-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25490" id="menu-item-25490">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/ascoli-piceno/">
                                    Ascoli Piceno</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25491" id="menu-item-25491">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/vallata/">
                                    La Vallata</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25492" id="menu-item-25492">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/riviera/">
                                    La Riviera</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25493" id="menu-item-25493">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/sibillini/">
                                    I Sibillini</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25494" id="menu-item-25494">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/regione/">
                                    Le Marche</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-25495" id="menu-item-25495">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/cronaca/">
                                    Cronaca</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25496" id="menu-item-25496">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/politica/">
                                    Politica</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25497" id="menu-item-25497">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/economia/">
                                    Economia</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25498" id="menu-item-25498">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/cultura/">
                                    Cultura</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25499" id="menu-item-25499">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/sport/">
                                    Sport</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25500" id="menu-item-25500">
                                    <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/eventi/">
                                    Eventi</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <p class="clipmask" id="breadcrumbs">Sei in:
                    <span><span><a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it" rel=
               "v:url">Home</a></span> » <span><a href=
               "http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/cronaca/" rel=
               "v:url">Cronaca</a></span> » <span><strong class=
               "breadcrumb_last">Colpo grosso al centro commerciale,
                cinque arresti</strong></span></span>
                </p>

                <h6 class="clipmask">PrimaPaginaOnline.it</h6>

                <div class="social-holder headsearch" id="top-search">
                    <form action="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/" class="searchform" method="get">
                        <label class="assistive-text" for="s"></label>
                        <input class="field s" id="s" name="s" placeholder="" type="text">
                        <input class="submit searchsubmit" name="submit" type="submit" value="">
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div id="social-pages">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PrimaPaginaOnline" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="Pagina Facebook di Prima Pagina Online" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/facebook.png?a54f70" title="Vai alla pagina Facebook di Prima Pagina Online">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/primapaginaon" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="Account Twitter di Prima Pagina Online" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/twitter.png?a54f70" title="Vai all'account Twitter di Prima Pagina Online">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/PrimaPaginaOnline" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="Canale Youtube di Prima Pagina Online" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/youtube.png?a54f70" title="Vai al canale Youtube di Prima Pagina Online">
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/+PrimapaginaonlineIt/" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="Pagina Google+ di Prima Pagina Online" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/gplus.png?a54f70" title="Vai alla pagina Google+ di Prima Pagina Online">
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/PrimaPaginaOnline-Feed" target="_blank">
                        <img alt="Feed RSS di Prima Pagina Online" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/themes/pponline/images/rss.png?a54f70" title="Leggi il feed RSS di Prima Pagina Online">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="cb"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="leaderbanner" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <a class="gofollow" data-track="MTIsNCwwLDE=" href="http://www.paliodelduca.it/mercato.html" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
                    <img alt="Sponsalia, rievocazione storica di Acquaviva Picena" src="http://95.110.225.62/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/banner-sponsalia.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="cb"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- main -->

    <section id="main">
        <div class="site-content content-holder primary" id="content-wrapper">
            <header>
                <figure>
                    <img alt="arresti" class="attachment-topimage wp-post-image" data-lazy-src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/polizia-675x250.jpg?a54f70" height="250" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/plugins/lazy-load/images/1x1.trans.gif?a54f70" width="675">
                    <noscript>
                        <img alt="arresti" class="attachment-topimage wp-post-image" height="250" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/polizia-675x250.jpg?a54f70" width="675">
                    </noscript>
                </figure>

                <div class="single-page-category">
                    Cronaca
                </div>

                <h1 class="entry-title single-entry-title">Colpo grosso al
                centro commerciale, cinque arresti</h1>

                <div class="meta-description">
                    Scattati gli arresti. Coinvolti nel furto tre esperti del crimine, ma anche una guardia giurata e un addetto alla sicurezza del centro commerciale ascolano.
                </div>

                <div class="single-post-meta"></div>
            </header>

            <div class="single-wrapper" id="content">
                <!-- .entry-header -->

                <section>
                    <div id="single-heading-content">
                        <div class="single-right-big">
                            <article class="post-26749 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-cronaca tag-al-battente tag-arresti tag-guardia-giurata tag-questura-ascoli-piceno tag-sicurezza" id="post-26749">
                                <h6 class="clipmask">Testo articolo
                                principale</h6>

                                <div class="entry-content">
                                    <p>ASCOLI PICENO – Arrestati i responsabili della rapina da 85mila euro al centro commerciale Al Battente di Ascoli Piceno avvenuta il <strong>10
                                    giugno 2013</strong>; scattano le manette per cinque persone tra cui una guardia giurata e un addetto alla sicurezza. A distanza di un anno sono stati trovati i responsabili del
                                        <strong>furto</strong>, compiuto in pochi secondi da due persone con indosso il casco da motociclista.</p>

                                    <p>La Questura di Ascoli Piceno ha illustrato le dinamiche di quella notte, quando poco dopo la mezzanotte i due uomini sono entrati con le chiavi, hanno aperto le serrande e disattivato l’allarme per raggiungere la cassaforte.
                                    </p>

                                    <p>Cinque gli uomini coinvolti, custodia cautelare in carcere per O.M. 63enne di Pescara e G.C. 58enne di Macerata che avrebbero compiuto materialmente il furto, mentre arresti domiciliari per A.C. 57enne di Ascoli, G.S. 37enne ascolano e B.F. 65enne di Macerata. Tra loro anche una
                                        <strong>guardia giurata</strong> e un
                                        <strong>addetto alla sicurezza</strong>
                                        del centro commerciale che avrebbe fornito le chiavi. Descritta come una vera e propria banda del crimine, ognuno ha ricoperto un ruolo determinante per la riuscita del colpo. I furfanti, infatti, hanno effettuato sopralluoghi e riprese per monitorare e studiare i transiti degli addetti alla sicurezza del centro commerciale,</p>

                                    <p>Fin dalle prime
                                        <strong>indagini</strong> è emerso che alcuni componenti possedevano una non comune abilità e una capacità tecnica e organizzativa altamente professionale, scaturita, per loro stessa ammissione, dalla pregressa appartenenza alle famigerate bande
                                        <strong>Viccei</strong> e
                                        <strong>Battestini</strong>, gruppi malavitosi che tra la fine degli anni ‘70 e gli anni ’80 si erano resi responsabili di efferati crimini nelle regioni marchigiane e abruzzesi. A loro si sono poi uniti la guardia giurata che aveva il compito di ritardare l&#8217;intervento nel caso fosse scattato l&#8217;allarme e l&#8217;addetto alla sicurezza che ha consegnato le chiavi.</p>
                                </div>
                                <!-- .entry-content -->
                            </article>
                            <!-- #post-26749 -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- .single-right -->

                        <div class="cb"></div>
                    </div>

                    <p class="tags"><span class="tags-text">Tag:</span>
                        <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/tag/al-battente/" rel="tag">al battente</a>, <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/tag/arresti/" rel="tag">arresti</a>, <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/tag/guardia-giurata/" rel="tag">guardia giurata</a>, <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/tag/questura-ascoli-piceno/" rel="tag">questura ascoli piceno</a>, <a href="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/tag/sicurezza/" rel="tag">sicurezza</a>
                    </p>

                    <div class="home-post-meta">
                        scritto da <span>Dina Maria Laurenzi</span> - pubblicato il
                        <time datetime="2014-07-04T16:38:58+00:00">4 luglio 2014</time>- in <b><span><a href=
                       "http://www.primapaginaonline.it/categoria/cronaca/"
                       title=
                       "Visualizza tutti gli articoli in Cronaca">Cronaca</a></span></b>
                    </div>

                    <div class="social-container">
                        <div class="twitter-follow">
                            <a class="twitter-follow-button" data-dnt="true" data-lang="it" data-show-count="false" data-size="small" href="https://twitter.com/PrimaPaginaOn">Segui
                            @PrimaPaginaOn</a> 
                            <script>
                                ! function (d, s, id) {
                                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                                        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
                                    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                                        js = d.createElement(s);
                                        js.id = id;
                                        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                                    }
                                }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
                            </script>
                        </div>

                        <div class="like-button fb-like" data-action="like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PrimaPaginaOnline" data-layout="button_count" data-share="false" data-show-faces="true"></div>

                        <div class="plus-badge">
                            <a href="//plus.google.com/115446306534388049376?prsrc=3" rel="publisher" style="text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:#333;text-align:center; font:13px/16px arial,sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;" target="_blank"><span style=
                           "display:inline-block;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top;margin-right:5px; margin-top:0px;">
                            Prima Pagina Online</span><span style=
                           "display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin-right:13px; margin-top:0px;">su</span>
                            <img alt="Google+" src=
                           "//ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-16.png?a54f70"
                           style="border:0;width:16px;height:16px;"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cat-links-holder-single">
                        ARTICOLI CORRELATI
                    </div>

                    <div class="related">
                        <div class="relatedpost">
                            <h3><a href=
                           "http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/07/03/controlli-straordinari-sicurezza/"
                           rel="bookmark" title=
                           "Controlli straordinari per la sicurezza">Controlli
                            straordinari per la sicurezza</a></h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="relatedpost">
                            <h3><a href=
                           "http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/07/03/motociclista-contro-guardrail/"
                           rel="bookmark" title=
                           "Finisce contro il guardrail, attimi di paura sull&#8217;Ascoli-mare">
                            Finisce contro il guardrail, attimi di paura
                            sull&#8217;Ascoli-mare</a></h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="relatedpost">
                            <h3><a href=
                           "http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/07/02/nel-giallo-spunta-un-testimone/"
                           rel="bookmark" title=
                           "Giallo Sarchiè, spunta un testimone">Giallo
                            Sarchiè, spunta un testimone</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        /* <![CDATA[ */
                        var disqus_url = 'http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/07/04/furto-al-battente-cinque-arresti/';
                        var disqus_identifier = '26749 http://www.primapaginaonline.it/?p=26749';
                        var disqus_container_id = 'disqus_thread';
                        var disqus_domain = 'disqus.com';
                        var disqus_shortname = 'primapaginaonline';
                        var disqus_title = "Colpo grosso al centro commerciale, cinque arresti";
                        var disqus_config = function () {
                            var config = this; // Access to the config object
                            config.language = '';

                            /* Add the ability to add javascript callbacks */

                            /*
                                           All currently supported events:
                                           * preData — fires just before we request for initial data
                                           * preInit - fires after we get initial data but before we load any dependencies
                                           * onInit  - fires when all dependencies are resolved but before dtpl template is rendered
                                           * afterRender - fires when template is rendered but before we show it
                                           * onReady - everything is done
                                           */

                            config.callbacks.preData.push(function () {
                                // clear out the container (its filled for SEO/legacy purposes)
                                document.getElementById(disqus_container_id).innerHTML = '';
                            });
                            config.callbacks.onReady.push(function () {
                                // sync comments in the background so we don't block the page
                                var script = document.createElement('script');
                                script.async = true;
                                script.src = '?cf_action=sync_comments&post_id=26749';

                                var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                                firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
                            });
                        };
                        /* ]]> */
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        /* <![CDATA[ */
                        var DsqLocal = {
                            'trackbacks': [],
                            'trackback_url': "http:\/\/www.primapaginaonline.it\/2014\/07\/04\/furto-al-battente-cinque-arresti\/trackback\/"
                        };
                        /* ]]> */
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        /* <![CDATA[ */
                        (function () {
                            var dsq = document.createElement('script');
                            dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
                            dsq.async = true;
                            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.' + 'disqus.com' + '/' + 'embed' + '.js' + '?pname=wordpress&pver=2.77';
                            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                        })();
                        /* ]]> */
                    </script>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- #content -->
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: The [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) doesn't give this particular error for the file you have uploaded.

Comment: Well, it could be after the row that it says, I've pasted only the part of code before that. I'm searching but not finding anything

Comment: Please include a minimal example of your HTML giving this error; otherwise this question won’t be of any use when the links go 404 or you change your code.

Comment: @unor: In the post there is a link to a pastebin page with the code

Comment: @fas: I know, but a link to an external site is not sufficient: when the linked page gets deleted etc., your question here on SO would be of no use to anyone else anymore. That’s why everything required to answer your question should be included *in* your question. -- From Stack Overflow’s close reasons: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."

Comment: @unor: added the code of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the error, there was a `</section>` missing, before `</div><!-- #content -->` that was giving the error. In the code that i've posted it seemed all ok because I used an html beautifier that automatically added the missing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `Doctype`, it could be because you haven't self-closed your `<img>` tags. JSFiddle, for example, marks certain self-closing tags from XHTML as still open if you don't add a closing slash: `<img>`, `<input>`, and `<br>`, to name a few.

I looked through your code and couldn't find any open tags, either.

Comment: Yes, very strange. I can't find anything